# Dynamic indexing for data arranged in rows in excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, indexing

I have an excel sheet with the following in columns C2 through O2:

```
Month   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
```

In columns C3 through O3, I have the following:

```
Revenue 14.48828064 57.39890307 7.789366115 77.9224996  98.47631317 99.91713279 27.60377772 95.71525763 48.19843962 32.31745481 26.69196797 83.49167956
```

In columns C9 through D9, I have:

```
From Month |    1
```

And in columns C10 through D10:

```
Till month |    12
```

In column C12, I have:

```
Revenue
```

The problem I have is to prepare a formula in the cell D12 that will dynamically react to the changes of cells D9, D10 and bring the sum of line 3 - Revenue in cell D12, using only a formula in cell D12 without using any other cells.

I know how to do this when the data are vertically ordered, using the offset and INDIRECT functions, but have not been able to figure out a way when the data are ordered horizontally. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this formula in `D12`

```
=SUM(OFFSET(C3,0,D9,1,D10-D9+1))
```

it sums up the range specified with the `OFFSET` function. The range begins at the cell corresponding to the "from month", which is `0` rows down, and `D9` cols to the right, of the `C3` cell; comprises 1 row and `D10-D9+1` columns.

Comment: It does not seem to work. I get the message that the formula contains an error.

Comment: corrected, your excel does not like the `;` try commas `,` instead